# Cascade form second order sections with different impulse responses?

Tags: matrices

It is well documented in the digital signal processing literature that an impulse response for a FIR filter can be broken up into a cascade of identical second order sections. My interpretation is that the individual second order sections had identical impulse responses except perhaps for sign inversions on some of the weights.

I had read that it is possible to design a filter where the impulse responses of the second order sections were not identical. There is a paper written in the 70's discussing this concept but I can't find the paper either through IEEE explore or University engineering libraries.

"Design of two dimensional FIR filters from small generating kernels" by Abramatic and Faugeras.

In the above paper "small generating kernels" refers to using cascade form.

Thank You
Tom

Comment: Here ya go: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/1170706

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. Actually, I do have the paper that you refer to. However, the foundation paper that characterizes this idea is from the same author but I can not find it anywhere. 
0.D. FAUGERAS, J.F. ABRAMATIC. "2D FIR filters design from independent "small" generating kernels". International Conference on Digital Signal Processing. Florence, Italy. (September 1978).

IEEE Explore nor the engineering research libraries that I contact have access to this conference. I would love to get ahold of the original paper.